# SQL not in to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have a (Oracle)SQL query that I want to translate to Linq to use on a NHibernate context.
What the query does is to get me all the *Functions* that has been deleted from a given *Module* (ie. they don't exist in the given `module` but are linked to a predecessor *Module*)

```
"SELECT * FROM Function WHERE ModID = " + module.PredecessorID + "
   AND FncName NOT IN
      (SELECT FncName FROM Function WHERE ModId = " + module.ModID + " )"
```

Here is a image to explain the data model

[image]

I'm looking for an expression with the "dot notation", something like this:

```
DBContext.GetAll<Function>()
    .Where(x => x.Module.ModID == module.PredecessorID)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two steps (for readability).

```
var excludedNames = DbContext.GetAll<Function>()
                             .Where(x => x.ModeID == module.ModID)
                             .Select(x => x.FncName);

var result = DBContext.GetAll<Function>()
                      .Where(x => x.Module.ModID == module.PredecessorID &&
                                  !excludedNames.Contains(x.FncName));
```

Comment: Guess I could, but I would expect that NHibernate can't make that into only one SQL expression, and that would be preferable. (At least if feels like that would save some computational time right?)

Comment: @Markus : if you don't enumerate first query, this will be translated in one sql, not two.

Comment: don't enumerate? do you mean like `var excludedNames` instead of `List<Function> excludedNames = ....ToList()`?

Comment: well, you can use var, yes. Anyhow, if you don't put a .ToList() at the end, it's an `IEnumerable<string>` not a `List<string>` (we select `FncName` only, so it's no more a collection of `Function`.